# How are the parabolic cylindric functions to be used?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It may seem a weird question but the documentation about them is quite scarce. I will refer to the equations explained at this page:
https://archive.lib.msu.edu/crcmath/math/math/p/p058.htm

$$ y'' + (ax^2 + bx + c)y = 0 $$
Is the solution of the equation above a linear combination of 
$$y_1(x) = e^{-x^2/4}F(\frac{a}{2}+\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{x^2}{2}) $$ 
(even solutions)

and 
$$y_2(x) = xe^{-x^2/4}F(\frac{a}{2}+\frac{3}{4}, \frac{3}{2}, \frac{x^2}{2})$$ 
(odd solutions) ?

And what does it mean that the first equation up has two other standard forms?

Comment: why the -1? what's the problem?

Comment: Generally, people don't like having to go to other sites to understand your question.